# Emit to a components parents parent using defineEmits() in Vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Is it possible to emit to a components parents parent using defineEmits() in <script setup>?

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "close"): void
}>()

const closeParent = () => emit("close")    // emit this to parents parent
```

Functionally similar to:

```
<button type="button" @click="$parent!.$emit('close')">
```

Comment: `emit` always emits only to direct parent

Comment: Try using $listeners or $root.on